# Special price error on grouped products

Tags: grouped-products

Magento 1.8.1

I'm having a problem with special price and grouped products.
If I set a special price and and a "to date", the price on productview page changes to the normal price but not on the productlist page. See images...
Special price = 36,40
Normal price = 43,80

Why will the price not change on the productlist page?

[image: Productlist]

[image: Productview]

Answer (score 1):

You're not seeing the updated price on the ***product list*** page because product list page uses indexed data, where as the ***product view*** page pulls current data on the product.

Reindex the prices, and you should have your prices display properly.

Comment: Ok. Can I set up an automatic reindex for example every night? And how if it is possible?

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to set a system cron job. Do you not have any scheduled reindex on your environment?

Comment: No, I don't. But I can see it is nessesary.
I will try to find a tutorial on it.

Which interval will you suggest between the reindex cron jobs?

Comment: It really depends how often your product data changes. If you don't have any changes, then reindexing isn't necessary. How often do you update your products (any products)?